# Search plugin implementation

Tags: appexchange, c#, search, data-model

I have **zero** knowledge about the Salesforce/Force ecosystem.
I want to design and build an search plugin (with custom HTML rendering) and sell it as a plugin on the Apex platform.

Currently, the search service is exposed as a ASP.NET WebAPI (HTTP API) that can get the input search data and return a JSON file of the matching result.

I want to be able to access the entire [data model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api.meta/api/data_model.htm).

I want to ask:

1. What is the best choice for building such a search tool? Can Salesforce expose the data to my third party API or do I have to embed the code into Salesforce somehow?
2. Where/How can I sell my custom search component?
3. Are there any available examples of how custom components similar to what I'm trying to do? (tutorials, Github repose, etc. would be highly appreciated).

Comment: Ambitious. I'm curious why you want to sell a product on a platform you're completely unfamiliar with? Take a look at the Trailhead modules and the AppExchange. Also, please try to just ask one question per question.

Comment: I'm familiar with CRMs and ERPs and I've seen how SalesforceOne is implemented. Those Trailhead modules are ok, but I need someone who is more familiar with the overall ecosystem to point me the way.

Comment: And for I couldn't find anything relevant on AppExchange on how to design plugins for Salesforce (e.g. a HelloWorld plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best choice for building such a search tool? Can Salesforce expose the data to my third party API or do I have to embed the code into Salesforce somehow?

I believe you should make WebService callout from your Salesforce package to your search service.

> Where/How can I sell my custom search component?

You can package your search component as a custom managed package and sell it on AppExchange market if anyone finds it worthy to buy and if your component might be helpful to anyone.

> Are there any available examples of how custom components similar to what I'm trying to do? (tutorials, Github repose, etc. would be highly appreciated).

You can use trailhead or other material and read documentation about creation of Managed Packages and Salesforce ISP program.